# Pytorch RuntimeError:CUDA out of memory when training graph attention network

Tags: out-of-memory, pytorch, gpu, knowledge-graph

I am trying to reproduce the results of a model proposed in a paper with pytorch. This model uses the atttion mechanism to achieve the purpose of relationship prediction in the knowledge graph. It is mainly divided into two parts: graph attention network(GAT) and convolution network. The code for training GAT is as follows:

```
def train_gat(args):

    # Creating the gat model here.
    ####################################


    current_batch_2hop_indices = torch.tensor([])
    if(args.use_2hop):
        current_batch_2hop_indices = Corpus_.get_batch_nhop_neighbors_all(args,
                                                                          Corpus_.unique_entities_train, node_neighbors_2hop)

    if CUDA:
        current_batch_2hop_indices = Variable(
            torch.LongTensor(current_batch_2hop_indices)).cuda()
    else:
        current_batch_2hop_indices = Variable(
            torch.LongTensor(current_batch_2hop_indices))

    print("Defining model")

    print(
        "\nModel type -> GAT layer with {} heads used , Initital Embeddings training".format(args.nheads_GAT[0]))
    model_gat = SpKBGATModified(entity_embeddings, relation_embeddings, args.entity_out_dim, args.entity_out_dim,
                                args.drop_GAT, args.alpha, args.nheads_GAT)


    if CUDA:
        model_gat.cuda()
        model_gat=torch.nn.DataParallel(model_gat,device_ids=device_ids)


    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(
        model_gat.parameters(), lr=args.lr, weight_decay=args.weight_decay_gat)

    scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(
        optimizer, step_size=500, gamma=0.5, last_epoch=-1)

    gat_loss_func = nn.MarginRankingLoss(margin=args.margin)


    epoch_losses = []   # losses of all epochs
    print("Number of epochs {}".format(args.epochs_gat))

    for epoch in range(args.epochs_gat):
        print("\nepoch-> ", epoch)
        random.shuffle(Corpus_.train_triples)
        Corpus_.train_indices = np.array(
            list(Corpus_.train_triples)).astype(np.int32)

        model_gat.train()  # getting in training mode
        start_time = time.time()
        epoch_loss = []

        if len(Corpus_.train_indices) % args.batch_size_gat == 0:
            num_iters_per_epoch = len(
                Corpus_.train_indices) // args.batch_size_gat
        else:
            num_iters_per_epoch = (
                len(Corpus_.train_indices) // args.batch_size_gat) + 1

        for iters in range(num_iters_per_epoch):
            start_time_iter = time.time()
            train_indices, train_values = Corpus_.get_iteration_batch(iters)
            if CUDA:
                train_indices = Variable(
                    torch.LongTensor(train_indices)).cuda()
                train_values = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(train_values)).cuda()

            else:
                train_indices = Variable(torch.LongTensor(train_indices))
                train_values = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(train_values))

            # forward pass

            entity_embed, relation_embed = model_gat(
                Corpus_, Corpus_.train_adj_matrix, train_indices, current_batch_2hop_indices)

            optimizer.zero_grad()

            loss = batch_gat_loss(
                gat_loss_func, train_indices, entity_embed, relation_embed)

            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            epoch_loss.append(loss.data.item())

            end_time_iter = time.time()

            print("Iteration-> {0}  , Iteration_time-> {1:.4f} , Iteration_loss {2:.4f}".format(
                iters, end_time_iter - start_time_iter, loss.data.item()))

        scheduler.step()
        print("Epoch {} , average loss {} , epoch_time {}".format(
            epoch, sum(epoch_loss) / len(epoch_loss), time.time() - start_time))
        epoch_losses.append(sum(epoch_loss) / len(epoch_loss))

        save_model(model_gat, args.data, epoch,
                   args.output_folder)
```

The code to calculate the loss of the GAT is as follows:

```
def batch_gat_loss(gat_loss_func, train_indices, entity_embed, relation_embed):
    len_pos_triples = int(
        train_indices.shape[0] / (int(args.valid_invalid_ratio_gat) + 1))

    pos_triples = train_indices[:len_pos_triples]
    neg_triples = train_indices[len_pos_triples:]

    pos_triples = pos_triples.repeat(int(args.valid_invalid_ratio_gat), 1)

    source_embeds = entity_embed[pos_triples[:, 0]]
    relation_embeds = relation_embed[pos_triples[:, 1]]
    tail_embeds = entity_embed[pos_triples[:, 2]]

    x = source_embeds + relation_embeds - tail_embeds
    pos_norm = torch.norm(x, p=1, dim=1)

    source_embeds = entity_embed[neg_triples[:, 0]]
    relation_embeds = relation_embed[neg_triples[:, 1]]
    tail_embeds = entity_embed[neg_triples[:, 2]]

    x = source_embeds + relation_embeds - tail_embeds
    neg_norm = torch.norm(x, p=1, dim=1)

    y = -torch.ones(int(args.valid_invalid_ratio_gat) * len_pos_triples).cuda()

    loss = gat_loss_func(pos_norm, neg_norm, y)
    return loss
```

The datasets used to train the model in this paper are FB15k-237, NELL-995 and umls. The numbers of triples in their training set are: 272115 ,149678 and 5216. I successfully reproduced the results on all three datasets. However, when I tried to use a new dataset YAGO3-10 (with 1079040 training data) to train the model, I got a GPU memory overflow error. The error message is as follows：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 366, in <module>
    train_gat(args)
  File "main.py", line 240, in train_gat
    gat_loss_func, train_indices, entity_embed, relation_embed)
  File "main.py", line 149, in batch_gat_loss
    x = source_embeds + relation_embeds - tail_embeds
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 1.61 GiB (GPU 0; 15.77 GiB total capacity; 14.24 GiB already allocated; 120.25 MiB free; 440.29 MiB cached)
```

The methods I have tried are as follows:

1. Reduce the batch size. After reduction, it will overflow during backpropagation. The error message is as follows:

   `Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "main.py", line 366, in <module>
       train_gat(args)
     File "main.py", line 242, in train_gat
       loss.backward()
     File "/home/user1/anaconda3/envs/stw/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 107, in backward
       torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
     File "/home/user1/anaconda3/envs/stw/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 93, in backward
       allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
   RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 2.60 GiB (GPU 0; 15.77 GiB total capacity; 11.86 GiB already allocated; 2.42 GiB free; 511.96 MiB cached)`
2. Use torch.cuda.empty_cache () to remove useless variables before backpropagation. However, the maximum memory usage does not seem to change.
3. Use dataparallel to train model on two GPUs, but did not run successfully, it seems because some model parameters are on different GPUs. The error message is as follows:

   `Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "main.py", line 377, in <module>
       train_gat(args)
     File "main.py", line 244, in train_gat
       Corpus_, Corpus_.train_adj_matrix_dim1, Corpus_.train_adj_matrix_dim00, Corpus_.train_adj_matrix_dim01 ,train_indices, current_batch_2hop_indices)
     File "/home/user1/anaconda3/envs/stw/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 493, in __call__
       result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
     File "/home/user1/anaconda3/envs/stw/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 152, in forward
       outputs = self.parallel_apply(replicas, inputs, kwargs)
     File "/home/user1/anaconda3/envs/stw/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 162, in parallel_apply
       return parallel_apply(replicas, inputs, kwargs, self.device_ids[:len(replicas)])
     File "/home/user1/anaconda3/envs/stw/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/parallel_apply.py", line 83, in parallel_apply
       raise output
     File "/home/user1/anaconda3/envs/stw/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/parallel_apply.py", line 59, in _worker
       output = module(*input, **kwargs)
     File "/home/user1/anaconda3/envs/stw/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 493, in __call__
       result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
     File "/home/user1/cxy/KBAT-2/models.py", line 148, in forward
       edge_list, edge_type, edge_embed, edge_list_nhop, edge_type_nhop)
     File "/home/user1/anaconda3/envs/stw/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 493, in __call__
       result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
     File "/home/user1/cxy/KBAT-2/models.py", line 55, in forward
       for att in self.attentions], dim=1)
     File "/home/user1/cxy/KBAT-2/models.py", line 55, in <listcomp>
       for att in self.attentions], dim=1)
     File "/home/user1/anaconda3/envs/stw/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 493, in __call__
       result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
     File "/home/user1/cxy/KBAT-2/layers.py", line 140, in forward
       edge_m = self.a.mm(edge_h)
   RuntimeError: arguments are located on different GPUs at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1556653183467/work/aten/src/THC/generic/THCTensorMathBlas.cu:255`
4. Use apex package for float16 calculation. However, some parameters will report nan values, which may be the cause of using float16.

The latter two methods may work, but I haven't run the code successfully. I would like to ask if anyone has some experience using the above method, or has better suggestions.

Due to space limitations, I cannot show all the code. The code link of the model is as follows:
https://github.com/deepakn97/relationPrediction